# Jquery Mobile and Swipe JS incompatibility causes select list not to work on Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, swipe

I'm using jquery mobile 1.0 in combination with swipejs.  The [swipejs](http://swipejs.com/) library is being used to allow for mobile swipe gesture on a image carousel.  However, I've encountered an issue on Android 2.2.3 (Motorola Droid) and other Android devices where select lists (on the same page as swipejs) simply don't work.  The select lists appear but the native options menu's don't pop up, clicking them simply does nothing.  I was able to not only narrow it down to the swipejs, but also to a particular line within swipejs.

```
style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + -(index * this.width) + 'px,0,0)';
```

It appears that the transalate3d css behavior somehow interferes with jquery mobile select lists.  I've found numerous reports of the fragility of jquery mobile select lists on Android (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1051 ).  And have been able to create a fairly simple sample page the exhibits this behavior.  My fix was to alter the translate3d to translate in the swipejs library itself.  But I'm wondering if someone with a better understanding of what translate3d does and how that might effect jquery mobile might be able to proprose a better solution or is this a bug with jqm or swipejs?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/mobile/homeIcon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/images/mobile/splash.png" />
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });

    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="main">
        <header data-role="header">
        </header>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="select-choice-1">
                    Shipping method:</label>
                <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1" data-theme="a">
                    <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                    <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                    <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                    <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="divProductImagesCarousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="image_0.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_0.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_1.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_1.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_2.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_2.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_3.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_3.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_4.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_4.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_5.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_5.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_6.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_6.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_7.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_7.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_8.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_8.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="image_9.jpg">
                        <img width="250" height="250" src="image_9.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/master/swipe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var productImagesCarousel = document.getElementById('divProductImagesCarousel');
            window.mySwipe = new Swipe(productImagesCarousel);          
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a swipe library when using jQuery Mobile. You can register event handlers to the `swipeleft` and `swiperight` events:

```
$(document).delegate('#divProductImagesCarousel', 'swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {
    alert('You just ' + event.type + 'ed!');
});
```

Comment: That swipejs library also creates the carousel which I also need.

Comment: @JNappi Can you post a link to a working example, perhaps a JSFiddle?

Comment: I had considered that and started down the jsfiddle road but found that hard to test on the actual android device so I figured the full html example that you could plop on a webserver locally somewhere would be easier.

Comment: @JNappi In JSFiddle you can add `/embedded/result/` to the end of a URL and it will display the JSFiddle full screen. Here is an example using a JSFiddle I made this morning: http://jsfiddle.net/VP25m/embedded/result/

Comment: I'll give credit for this one, its as close an answer as I'm likely to get.

Comment: -1  This is not solving the problem at all. If swipe must be there for a customer requirement, and we have the bad luck to have a dropdown inside the carousel area, the stuff still does not work in Android. I'm investigating this issue at the moment.

Comment: @opalenzuela If SwipeJS works like other swipe libraries then it will `return false` on `touchstart` for the element to which it's bound, this is to stop the default behavior of scrolling. So having elements within the swipe-element should stop the propagation of the `touchstart` event so it won't be canceled by the library. And yeah, I'm surprised this was marked as accepted as it was basically a suggestion to change libraries (maybe write your own slider code, its pretty simple).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, jQueryMobile has its own swipe function

BUT!. swipeJS is so nice!
And you can still use it!

This took me a lot of investigating, but i found a solution that works for me.

Basically, just put all the swipejs stuff inside $(document).ready(function(){

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// outside ready function so that buttons still have a var to attach function calls to like slider.next()
var slider;

// process AFTER jquery mobile. 
// i "think" the problem that somehow jquery mobile stops swipejs from detecting the width of the div (in the setup function) 
$(document).ready(function(){

    slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('myslider'), {
        callback: function(e, pos) {  
             // some callback code here
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I don't think this is a conflict in JS -- perhaps. 
This forces swipejs to be processed at the end,
and presumably after whatever jquerymobile feature is messing it up.

I'm pretty new to JS, so I don't know how this function differs from the other "do this last" type functions. This might cause other nasty conflicts, I suppose. 
If someone wants to comment with a better function (and why), that would be great too.

Comment: Thank you so much <3 simple but effective solution

Comment: Watch-out for using `document.ready` in a jQuery Mobile site: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html (Notice the big yellow box at the top)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use jquerymobile "pageshow" method, not the pageinit or something others.
The code example below:

```
$(document).live('pageshow', function(){
  //put the swipejs code here.
}
```